# How to send calendar events through ajax response in jquery fullcalendar

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, codeigniter, fullcalendar

I am using jQuery Fullcalendar with Codeigniter. Firstly I have a table with schedule time and name. I am sending data to `fullcalendar.js` when I am loading calendar page but I want in ajax response. How I am proceed? Please help me.

I have tried below code.

```
function get_locationdata(start, end) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: '<?php echo base_url(); ?>/index.php/Task_controller/get_schedulelocationsdata',    
        data: {
            start: start,
            end: end,
            user_id: user_id
        },
        success: function(resp) {
            defaultEvents = resp;
        }
    });
}

defaultEvents = resp;

<script src = '<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/plugins/fullcalendar/dist/fullcalendar.min.js'></script>
<script src = "<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/pages/jquery.fullcalendar.js"></script>
```

`defaultEvents` is an array which I sent to `jquery.fullcalendar.js`
and in resp I am getting `json_encoded` data.I want to send events to `fullcalendar.js` using ajax response.

Comment: Normally you tell fullCalendar the location of your events data, either directly by giving the URL (if it's compliant with what fullCalendar specifies, as per: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_data/events_json_feed/. In your case, since you use a POST request, it's not compliant, so unless you can change that, you can use this pattern instead: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_data/events_function/. Try that. If you get stuck, post your updated code here.

Comment: P.S. Is "jquery.fullcalendar.js" a copy of jQuery, or a copy of fullCalendar? If it's jquery, it should be added _before_ fullCalendar (and also you need the other dependencies such as momentJS, as per https://fullcalendar.io/docs/usage/). If it's another copy of fullCalendar, then you should remove it, because you already loaded fullCalendar on the line above it.

Comment: jquery.fullcalendar.js is copy of fullcalendar.

Comment: As @ADyson said, you already include `fullcalendar.min.js`.  What is `jquery.fullcalendar.js`?

Comment: Do you mean it is *your* Fullcalendar code, initialising your calendar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to get your events would be to change your feed from a POST feed to GET.  Then all you need to do is pass the URL to Fullcalendar, and everything just works.

If that's not possible, you will have to re-arrange your code.  Your AJAX call is asynchronous, which means it won't finish and get results immediately, and your code below it (eg the second line `defaultEvents = resp;`) will not have access to any results returned from the AJAX - `resp` is undefined at that point.

So you need to initialise your Fullcalendar when the AJAX completes, in the success callback.  This assumes your AJAX POST returns set of events [correctly formatted and as expected by Fullcalendar](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_data/) (eg an array).  If they are not in the right format, you'll need to process them in your AJAX `success` callback.

```
function get_locationdata(start, end) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: '<?php echo base_url(); ?>/index.php/Task_controller/get_schedulelocationsdata',
        data: {
            start: start,
            end: end,
            user_id: user_id
        },
        success: function(resp) {
            // Now you have your event data, you can fire up Fullcalendar
            initFullcalendar(resp);
        }
    });
}

function initFullcalendar(events) {
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        // ...
        events: events,
    });
}

// Fire everything off
get_locationdata('2017-10-10', '2017-11-10');
```

Note though that by providing a static set of events to Fullcalendar, it means they won't be updated as you change views.  So if you click the calendar navigation buttons to see next month, the events won't be updated.  Unless you loaded *all* past, present and future events in your initial `get_locationdata()` call, you won't see new events for the new month.  You'll need to come up with some solution involving the `viewRender` callback, so that when the view is changed (eg clicking to a new month), you can fire off a new AJAX request to get new events.

Comment: I am trying above code. But in initFullCalendar function i am trying to initialize calendar. But events are not sent to calendar page. It is the main problem. Please help.

Comment: @Anuradha are you passing the response from your AJAX call (`resp` in my code above) to `initFullcalendar()`? And is it valid event data?

Comment: Yes, I am passing the data via ajax call and in resp the data will come as json encoded data.

Comment: @Anuradha Is it [valid event data](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_data/Event_Object/)?

Comment: When i load the page in controller i am passing some data . It is working. I am loading some more data in ajax and i am passing same as the controller data. at that time it is not working.

Comment: @Anuradha This code is working for me locally.  Make sure your AJAX is returning valid JSON, maybe try adding `header('Content-Type: application/json');`.  Try using `console.log()` and `console.dir()` to check data along each step.